# Understanding the relation between quotient rings and polynomial quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation, quotient-group

I am studying the proof of [Proposition 1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/047.pdf) and I don't understand the following two statements.

> As $p\mid\Delta_K$ the group $(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K}/p\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})^*$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2))^*$. This group contains $p(p-1)$ elements of the form $a+b\sqrt{\Delta_K}$ where $a\in (Z/pZ)^*$ and $b\in Z/pZ$

Here, $\Delta_K=-p$ and $\Delta_K\equiv1\pmod4$.

How did they come up with the isomorphism and why does the latter contain elements of the form $a+b\sqrt{\Delta_K}$? I do not have a background in group/ring theory and hence the question.

Comment: Look at the ring structure of $R = \{ a+i b p^{1/2}, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \}$. It has $p^2$ elements. The addition is defined as usual modulo $p$, and the multiplication is defined by $(a+ib p^{1/2})(c+id p^{1/2}) = ac+i(bc+ad) p^{1/2}$. Thus $a+ibp^{1/2}$ is inversible iff $a \ne 0 \bmod p$. Finally show $a+bX \mapsto a+ibp^{1/2}$ is a ring isomorphism $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2) \to R$. In your book $\Delta_K$ can be $-qp$ with $p \nmid q$, and it works the same way.

Comment: Your comment doesn't explain why $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$ has elements of the form of the elements of $R$ you mentioned(assuming $R=$$\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$). $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$ has elements of the form $a+b\frac{\Delta_K+\sqrt{\Delta_K}}{2}$

Comment: With $ \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{p}]= \{ a+i b \sqrt{p}, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ then it is clear that $ \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{p}]/(p) = \{a+ib\sqrt{p}, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\}$ and as I said it works the same way with $i\sqrt{p}$ replaced by $i\sqrt{qp}, p \nmid q$. If $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+i\sqrt{p}}{2}]$ then for $p$ odd : $\mathcal{O}_K/(p) = \{a+b\frac{1+i\sqrt{p}}{2}, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\}=\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{p}]/(p)$ because $2$ is inversible modulo $p$

Comment: The elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$ look like $Z+\frac{\Delta_K+\sqrt{\Delta_K}}{2}Z$

Comment: No for $-p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+i\sqrt{p}}{2}] = \{a+b\frac{1+i\sqrt{p}}{2}, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, but once reduced modulo $p$ it doesn't change anything

Comment: If $\mathcal{O}_K$ elements look like the representation you specify, why is $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{\Delta_K}}{2}\right]$?

Comment: I tried to detail everything above, the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ has elements of the form $a+\alpha b$ when $\alpha$ is the root of a monic irreducible integer polynomial (in the same way that $\mathbb{C}= \{a+ib\}$)